# $\exp(a)+\exp(b)+\exp(c)\leq \exp(1)+\exp(0)+\exp(0)$ when $0\leq a,b,c\leq 1$ and $a+b+c=1$

Tags: inequality, optimization, exponential-function, convex-optimization

It seems that:

Under the constraint of:

$x_1+x_2+...+x_n=1, 0\le x_1,x_2,...,x_n \le 1$,

We have:

$e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}+...+e^{x_n} \le e^1+e^0+...+e^0$

And it is equal only when one of the $x$ reaches $1$ and others remain $0$.

Is there mathematical proof to explain it?

Comment: I can't quite connect it yet but maybe Jensen's inequality could be useful here. Not sure though.
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)

Comment: Can you clarify the first two constraints? They seem redundant to me. Typo?

Comment: Comparing with the title, I can see that it was a typo. You probably meant to say that each $x_i$ is between $0$ and $1$, not their sum.

Comment: @StefanLafon That's my mistake. Now I've fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @Eric Sorry to make you confused. There's a mistake in my question and now I've fixed it. Thanks for your comment anyway.

Comment: It's just an application of Karmata's inequality .Good luck !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint :

$e^x$ is an convex function ( for all $x$ and in particular for $x\geq 0$ ),  and the vector $(1,0\cdots,0)$ majorizes the vector $(x_1,...,x_n)$ .So we can apply Karamata's inequality

Comment: Thanks! Karamata's inequality is amazing!

Answer (score 7):

The function $$(x_1, \ldots x_n) \mapsto e^{x_1} + \ldots + e^{x_n}$$ on $\mathbb R^n$ is a sum of convex functions and therefore convex.  So on any compact convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$ it takes its maximum in an extreme point.  For the convex hull of the standard basis vectors it is therefore maximal in a basis vector (and, by symmetry, in all basis vectors).

Comment: So the maximum of a convex function on a convex hull of n points is always on one of the n points?

Comment: @Thomas Sure. Of course there can be other points as well (for example if the function is constant).

Comment: For curiosity how do you formalize it? I think you have to use that the restriction of a convex function to a segment contained in a convex domain is convex as well, and that the maximum in a segment is achieved at one of the extremes, but I do not see how to formalize it easily...

Comment: @Thomas Every element of a compact convex set is a convex combination of its extreme points, and if $x=\sum_k \lambda_k x_k$ and $f$ is convex, then $f(x)\leq \sum_k \lambda_k f(x_k)\leq \max_k f(x_k)$. Thus $f$ attains its maximum at an extreme point.

Comment: Right I was thinking too much geometrically. Thanks!